# Set Python Path in Windows 10 to Install Third-Party Python Packages

Tags: python, windows, powershell, installation, libraries

My IT department does not give me the ability to use pip or easy install to install Python library packages from PyPi.

At some point I figured out that I could download the Python packages, extract the contents with 7-Zip until I exposed the setup.py file.  Then by opening the command line in this same location I could type

`set path=%path%;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\`

and

`python setup.py install`

to install the libraries into my Python directory.  This trick worked perfectly on Windows 7.

I have since been 'upgraded' to Windows 10.  When I try my installation trick the Windows PowerShell returns this

```
PS C:\TEMP\simplekml-1.3.1> set path=%path%;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\ : The term 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ set path=%path%;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I install these Python Packages in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to edit environment variables like so:

```
$env:path = $env:path + ";C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\"
```

Please check beforehand if there is a semicolon at the end of `$env:path` or not.

Comment: Thanks, switching from the command line argument set path=%path%;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\ to the PowerShell command $env:path = $env:path + ";C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\" worked.

Answer (score -1):

You may not get access to set up the environmental path or any other other files to set up in C: drive, better you download in desktop and unzip the Python files and go to script and go to command prompt with the path and try to install using PIP because you have full control on desktop no need to ask permissions.